# Align image with text properly

Tags: css, reactjs

So I have created this app that lets me get data from API and display them like this:

[image: pics]

So as u can see the images and title are perfectly centered but the images are not well organized u can see they are not centered under each others properly how can I fix this?

code:

```
<div className="container text-center">
    <div className="row">
                    {newPhotosLocally.map(picture =>{
                        return(
                        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <PostItem 
                        key={picture.id}
                        src={picture.thumbnailUrl} 
                        thumbnailUrl={picture.thumbnailUrl} 
                        onClick={() => showPicture(picture.url,picture.id,picture.title)}
                        title={picture.title}/>
                        </div>
                        )
                    })}  
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

PostItem.js:

```
<div>
          <div className="container text-center">
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-4 "></div>
        <div className="item">
            <img src={src} onClick={onClick} alt="small post"></img>
            <div className="caption">{title}</div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

css code:

```
div.item {
    vertical-align: top;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    text-align: center;
    /* width: 120px; */
}

.caption {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Paulie_D this is actually a snippet of the code related to the images and how i styled them using bootstrap and css

Comment: @M.I Can you upload a working demo ? It's hard to guess styles from this. Otherwise can you post the static html without the component ( PostItem.js ) usage ?